# Sort chart in qlikview

Tags: qlikview

Hello I did sort in my chart but it doesn't work,
i don't know why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your sorting now? You must sort your second dimension by the expression you are using.

**Edit**

Have a look at this:
https://community.qlik.com/thread/181828

They solve the problem using aggr()

//micke

Comment: that what I did, I sort  my dimension by expression that work but i see that sum value it's not sorted very well